# Keep container running when using agent docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have this script run in sequential stages:

```
stage("Set up first image"){
        agent {
            docker {
                label "${RUNNING_NODE}"
                image "${IMAGE}"
                reuseNode true
            }
        }
        steps {
            echo "This is treasure!"
        }
    }
```

And this is output:

```
16:01:55  [Pipeline] {
16:01:55  [Pipeline] echo
16:01:55  This is treasure!
16:01:55  [Pipeline] }
16:01:55  $ docker stop --time=1 ca63
16:01:56  $ docker rm -f ca63
16:01:56  [Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
```

Docker stops container immediately after stage is built, but I want this container alive to use in another stage. **Is there any way to keep container still running after stage is built**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you want to do? what is the goal? there will be different answers for different purpose. for example you can run stages in parallel and use `sleep` in docker stage. while docker stage sleeps you can access container from another stage

Comment: So, Is there any way to keep container still running after stage is built in sequential stages?

Comment: yes, if you run container with `docker run -d` and then execute commands with `docker exec -tt` instead of using jenkins pipeline syntax. what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to upgrade my job by using jenkins pipeline syntax instead of using script (include commands like: docker run, docker exec,...) for several reasons. So, any solution, sir?